# select current class with jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the following html:

```
<div class="nav-1 anotherClass">menu one</div>
<div class="someClass nav-2">menu two</div>
```

Now, I would like to select the class like this:

```
var nav = $('[class^=nav]').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```

It gets nav-1 for first div and someClass for second div.

How can I get the class which starts with nav?

I tried this but not worked:

```
var nav = $('[class^=nav]').attr('class').split(' ')[this];
```

Is there any around simple?

Comment: we prefer to use another class to do that... class="nav nav-1" It is easier to use.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you not use a common class, and identify each using a second class or `data` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var nav = $('[class|=nav]').attr('class').match(/(nav-[^\s]+)/)[0];
```

or

```
$('[class|=nav]').each(function(){
    var nav = this.className.match(/(nav-[^\s]+)/)[0]
})
```

Comment: however, it's getting two times like nav-1, nav-1

Comment: @NavinRauniyar yes `var nav = $('[class|=nav]').attr('class').match(/(nav-[^\s]+)/)[0]`

Comment: why it's getting two times without [0] ?

Comment: because the `.match()` returns an array

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there's no simple way of getting at a particular class. You have to loop through all classes:

```
var navList = $('[class*=nav]').attr('class').split(' ');
var nav;
for(var i in navList) {
    if(navList[i].indexOf('nav') === 0) { nav = navList[i]; break; }
}
```

---

That's why it's common to use custom html attributes, e.g.

```
<div class="nav anotherClass" data-custom-value=1>menu one</div>
<div class="someClass nav" data-custom-value=2>menu two</div>
```

And...

```
var navNumber = $('.nav').attr('data-custom-value');
```

Comment: How, can I use first method? try giving me an example to alert nav-1 for first div and nav-2 for second div.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Also, just noticed this: using `[class|=nav]` or `[class^=nav]` only matches the first element (where `nav-1` is the first class). Use `*=` to match both.